# Siri on MacOS does not work with HomeKit

Tags: imac, mojave, siri, homekit

I have a number of Philips Hue lights which I can control from my iPhone using the Hue & Home apps as well as Siri. As long as I am connected to the wifi everything works well.

After updating to Mac OS Mojave I now have the Home app on my iMac which has a wired ethernet connection to the same Hub as the Philips Hue bridge. I also have the same Home app configuration on my Macbook as well.

Using the Home app on the iMac & Macbook I can reliably control all of the Hue lights.

Unfortunately Control of the lights using Siri on the iMac and Macbook is very unreliable. Most of the time Siri responds with something like "You have not setup any devices in you Home" even though yet they exist in the Home app.

Very occaisionally Siri will control a light but that is very rare.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a hidden confoguration option to ensure that Siri has the same access as the Home app?

Am I expecting too much from Siri on iMac/Macbook and should I just accept that Apple will fix this in a few years time?